# Robocopy Server 2003 does not support the /mt option

Tags: windows-server-2003, robocopy

I am doing a rather large transfer (8TB) from inside our network to another network share. Most of the files are ranging anywhere to .1 MB to 15 MB. The machine that I need to do the copying on is Windows Server 2003.

I am familiar with robocopy and specifically the /mt option to increase the amount of threads to deal with the rather small file sizes and large amount of files that will need to be copied. I have downloaded the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657). Which includes robocopy but it seems like the version included does not offer the option for /mt, dramatically slowing down the transfer.

Is there a way to get the robocopy with the /mt option working on server 2003?

Comment: You could try copying the binary over from a Win7/2008R2 machine, but if that doesn't work you're probably out of luck.

Comment: @ryanries Yea unfortunately I tried that, it does not work.

Comment: What was the error on the Win2k3 box when running the Win2k8R2 version?  Are you running Win2k3 x86 or x64?

Comment: @SimonCatlin Roboocopy is not a valid win32 application. The file came from windows 7 x 86 and the server is x86 as well.

Comment: Are you only making one invocation of robocopy from the root of the sahre? Try making a unique invocation of robocopy for each dir at the root of the share. Use "start" in batch or "start-job" in powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up just spawning 8 different instances of the application. Wrote a simple script that spawned the next instance once was finished. So I always had 8 instances running at once (until it got towards the end).

Answer (score 1):

From TechNet: "The /MT parameter applies to Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7."

So it doesn't look like the /MT option is supported on W2K3.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try RichCopy. It does multithreaded copies, and also comes from Microsoft as a portable tool.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx